# PostCSS + CRA + Sass

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, postcss, postcss-cli

I just learned about PostCSS while looking for a way to polyfill a React application created using `create-react-app`.  The styling of this application is in `.scss` files, not the regular `.css` files.

I've been trying to follow [this tutorial](https://dev.to/puritanic/add-postcss-to-create-react-app--5hj8) but it's not working. Since the tutorial is 5 years old, I don't know if it's not relevant anymore or If I'm missing configuring something.

Below is my raw `package.json`. I did all the steps in the tutorial mentioned above and the only difference it makes is that I get this error message now:

```
Input Error: You must pass a valid list of files to parse
(node:63148) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onAfterSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:63148) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_BEFORE_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onBeforeSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ABC",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@googlemaps/react-wrapper": "^1.1.26",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.0.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.4.4",    
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.2",
    "@types/grecaptcha": "^3.0.4",
    "axios": "^0.23.0",
    "country-state-city": "^3.1.2",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",   
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "qs": "^6.10.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "^2.1.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.43.3",
    "react-i18next": "^11.18.6",
    "react-multi-carousel": "^2.6.5",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-responsive": "^9.0.0-beta.6",
    "react-router": "^6.8.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-actions": "^2.6.5",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^1.2.2",
    "redux-saga-test-plan": "^4.0.6",
    "simple-css-reset": "^3.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "styled-system": "^5.1.5",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  },
  "scripts": {   
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "env-cmd -f .env react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",   
    "format:check": "prettier --check .",
    "format:fix": "prettier --write .",
    "lint:check": "eslint .",   
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.2",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.179",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.37",
    "@types/qs": "^6.9.7",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@types/react-google-recaptcha": "^2.1.5",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.20",
    "@types/react-responsive": "^8.0.5",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "@types/redux-actions": "^2.6.2",
    "@types/redux-immutable-state-invariant": "^2.1.2",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.19",
    "@types/styled-system": "^5.1.15",
    "@types/testing-library__jest-dom": "^5.14.5",
    "eslint": "^8.36.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "prettier": "2.8.4",
    "sass": "^1.58.3"
  }
}
```

With this information is it possible to detect what I'm missing in my configuration?